# CloudDeploy a simple Manipulate fails

Tags: manipulate, cloud-deploy

I tried deploying a manipulate as an iframe using EmbedCode as follows, to no avail - my question is two-fold:

**1. How to get a basic manipulate to work as an iframe?**

- In all browsers?
- Without the wolfram cloud advertisement banner?

**2. How to protect it from users editing it?**

- What are the correct Permissions settings?
- Must you set them on both CloudDeply and EmbedCode?
- How to shrink wrap it so the user doesn't see lots of excess space?
- How to remove cell brackets?

Here is what I tried to deploy:

```
EmbedCode[
 CloudDeploy[
  Manipulate[
   ContourPlot3D[
    x^2 + y^2 + a z^3 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
    Mesh -> None], {a, -2, 2}], Permissions -> "Public"], 
 Permissions -> "Public"]
```

The result (in safari) is:

[image]

**Update:** It crashes less frequently in firefox, but is still weirdly editable:

[image]

Comment: Have you solved your problem in deploying your Manipulate. I have exactly the same issue. Please let me know if you have any answers to your question.

Answer (score 7):

This will do most of what you want:

```
Manipulate[
  ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + a z^3 == 1,
   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
   Mesh -> None],
  {a, -2, 2}] //

 EmbedCode[
   CloudDeploy[#, Permissions -> {All -> {"Read", "Interact"}}], 
   ImageSize -> {50, 80} + ImageDimensions@Rasterize@#] &
```

What this does:

It uses the `ImageSize` argument to `EmbedCode`. To get the dimensions of the `Manipulate` I did the standard `ImageDimensions@Rasterize` trick. The padding is just because `CloudCDF` (the output format for this sort of interactive material) is basically a notebook and I'm not sure there's a way to make it smaller or left-aligned.

Sadly, the concept of `WindowSize` in a cloud notebook isn't implemented (and it's not wholly clear what that should mean anyway) so there's no better way to shrink-wrap your `Manipulate`.

The bar seems to be there for good. WRI surely wants people to know that they developed the code for that.

Instead of `"Public"` use the explicit spec `All->{"Read","Interact"}`. `"Read"` because they need to see it. `"Interact"` because they should be able to move the manipulate. But since `"Write"` is not set, anything they do will *not* be saved. It will, however, eat your cloud credits. Unfortunately if you disable `"Interact"` it's not possible to see the content at all, because that first generation event is an interaction.

Of course, if you didn't want the `Manipulate` to be manipulable, you would have just deployed the plot.

When I deployed this, I didn't see cell brackets, which I'm guessing is a result of `"Write"` not being set. I was able to make new cells in the iframe, but no content appeared, which is what I think you want.

Comment: I followed your instructions above to deploy a `Manipulate` to my website. Interactivity is fine (in Firefox) but when someone else visits my website, `interactivity` does not work. It says `Starting Interactivity` but never starts it. Another issue is that I like to make the text in `Manipulate` in smaller fontsize and I do not know how to make it. Do you have an any idea how to solve my problems? Thanks.